# multiplication gives zero if I put elements into brackets (python)

Tags: python, division, multiplication

There is something extremely strange happening if I do some ordinary calculations in Python. If I do a multiplication whithout brackets, it gives the right thing, but if set some things into brackets the total multiplication becomes equal to zero.

For those who don't believe (I know that it sounds strange):

```
>>> print( 1.1*1.15*0.8*171*15625*24*(60/368*0.75)/1000000 )
0.0
>>> print( 1.1*1.15*0.8*171*15625*24*60/368*0.75/1000000 )
7.93546875
```

as shown in [this Jupyter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxLtm.png).

The only difference between both multiplications is that in the first there are brackets around `60/368*0.75`.

How is this possible and what can I do against it? I have no idea how this is even possible.

Comment: it's about operator priority, by eliminating parenthesis the equations will not be equal.

Comment: `*` and `/` have the same precedence, therefore omitting the paranthesis will just go from left to right.

Comment: but both calculations are equal, how can it gives such a difference? And how to prevent such things ? I noticed it by accident

Comment: They are not equal. `24*60/368` is not the same as `24*(60/368)`. Note that `/` is a truncating division in Python 2

Comment: @Felk what do you mean by 'not the same', I mean from a mathematically point of view they should be equal to each other

Comment: By 'not the same' I mean that the individual steps get evaluated in a different order, and `/` is an integer division in Python 2, which causes `60/368` to become 0. See Mureinik's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you divide integers `a`,`b` in python the result is the floor of the division, thus if `a < b` we get:
[image: floor(a,b)=0]

With brackets you have the operation `60/368` which gives `0`.

But without brackets the number `60` is first multiplied by everything before it, which results in some **double** value so dividing this value by `368` does not yield `0`.

Comment: `[dividing integers a/b in python, the result is the floor of the division` hair split: *in python 2*, or `a//b` in *python 3*.

Answer (score 2):

Parenthesis change the order of evaluation, and the expression inside them is evaluated first. Here, since 60 and 368 are both integer literals they are divided using [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers) - meaning only the "whole" part is kept. Since 60 is smaller than 368 their integer division is 0. From there on, the result is obvious - you've got a series of multiplications and divisions where one of multipliers is 0, so the end result would also be 0.

To prevent this you could express the numbers as floating point literals - 60.0 and 368.0. (Well, technically, just using 60.0 would be sufficient here, but for consistency's sake I recommend representing all the numbers as floating point literals).

Comment: The better solution imo, if possible, is to switch to Python 3, where `/` behaves as mathematically expected, and integer division has it's own `//` operator instead

Comment: @Felk porting an entire application to a newer version of the language, which dozens of subtle differences all over the show instead of just using a consistent convention for your numeric literals? Personally, I wouldn't.

Comment: That's why I said "if possible". I have no insight whether OP works on a big Python 2 codebase or writes code from scratch. And other people having the same problem might be able to start with Python 3

Comment: You can also `from __future__ import division` in py2 to get py3 behaviour.